# Uncaught TypeError: Blaze.Var is not a function

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

This one is driving me a little crazy.
I am playing with blaze and trying to create simple increment decrement with it.

here is my working code in codepen

http://codepen.io/distalx/pen/rVbQmm?editors=100

But when i am implementing it with meteor it gives me this error at following line

```
var counter = new Blaze.Var(0);
```

'Uncaught TypeError: Blaze.Var is not a function.'

here is meteorpad of it

http://meteorpad.com/pad/nhgMaMKNMQEainhcY/increment%20decrement

what am i doing wrong here.!!?

Comment: Please add all relevant code and data in **the question itself**. If the link dies your question and its answers lose most of their meaning! You can [edit] the code in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Codepen you are referring to uses an old version of Blaze (as a [standalone library](https://github.com/meteor/blaze)) which seems to not be maintained or updated anymore (see discussions in the Issues list). 
The version of Blaze used by Meteor is a package available [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/blaze) and it seems to differ a lot.
In fact, this version of Blaze does not have any `.Var()` method. 
But you can have the same functionalities by using a `ReactiveVar` with the [`reactive-var` package](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar).